# Can I use the Post-Receive URL Hook to abort a push?

Tags: github

In github I only want "integrator@mycompany.com" to have rights to push to the master branch. Can I acomplish this with the "Post-Receive URL Hook" provided by github?

Comment: Why not create a separate repo? The only issue with this is that if "integrator@mycompany.com" were to leave or change, you'd have to rewrite the hook, whereas if it were in a separate repo, you can just change the permissions in a lovely interface

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would keep two repos instead. integrator@mycompany.com maintains the "main" repo and the other repo is a fork of that. Whenever anyone wants to get something into main - they would issue a pull-request (or use format-patch and mail it) and the integrator can merge that into main.

integrator@mycompany.com would preferably also maintain the forked repo - merging main there (git fetch upstream etc.).